# Inno Setup Compiler able to uninstall awhile program is running

Tags: inno-setup

Right now when I need to uninstall the program I'm working on using the inno setup compiler. There is this issue that I'm able to uninstall the application when I run the application it shouldn't allow me to uninstall the application when it running. Is there any [setup] that I need to set up in the inno setup script? Any help will be great I can't find anything online that brings up this issue.

Comment: Thanks, CherryDT! Let me read this I couldn't find this article let me read it and implement it first and Ill let you know